# load recent nodes with node_load()

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

How can I load recent nodes with `node_load()`?

I used the following code, but I can't edit the links because it creates a list where they are inside it. I want to load the node IDs, and then use `node_load()` to load each node.

```
$output = db_query_range(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = '%s' AND n.status = 1 ORDER BY n.created DESC"), story, 0, 10));
print $output;
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `node_load()` you cannot get a list of the most recent nodes, as `node_load()` returns a single node object for the node that matches some criteria; it's not a function that returns a list of nodes.

The faster, but a little inefficient, way to get a list of more recent nodes is to:

- Get the list of node IDs associated with the most recent nodes
- Call `node_load()` for each of the node IDs obtained from the first step

You could use code similar to the following one.

```
   $nodes = array();
   $result = db_query_range("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n ORDER BY n.created DESC", array(), 0, $number_of_posts);

   while ($nid = db_result($result)) {
     $nodes[] = node_load($nid);
   }
```

After that code is executes, `$nodes` will contains the `$number_of_posts`th recent nodes.

Comment: Really Thanks, I tried this code but I couldn't get the result. maybe I'm missing something. can you make an example of showing list of nodes IDs ?

Comment: Did you define `$number_of_posts`? I tested the code, and it works.

Comment: Yes I did, I think I'm making a mistake somewhere. can you please tell me e.g. how to print all titles? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I changed `$nodes[]` to `$node` and it works fine now. I modified the code to show nodes from a specific term but it doesn't work. can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: That is a different question. `:)`

Comment: I'll try first, If failed I think I should open a new thread :D

Comment: just one thing, Is this code ok? I want to display newer posts first: `SELECT nid FROM term_node WHERE tid = '1' ORDER BY nid DESC`

Comment: That works, but it is making the assumption newer nodes have a higher node ID; while that is generally true, it is not necessary true. I would rather join that database table with the node table.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I had problem with `INNER JOIN` so I tried to use this method. Can you just make an example of what you're saying?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(n.nid) FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.vid = tn.vid WHERE tn.tid = '1' AND n.status = 1 ORDER BY n.created DESC`