# Load nodes from specific content type

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

Thanks to [kiamlaluno♦](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38983/load-recent-nodes-with-node-load/) I can load recent nodes using node_load() but how can I load recent nodes from a specific content type?

Comment: Do you want to include unpublished nodes? Is it for a listing (in which case you probably want to use [`db_rewrite_sql`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always enclose the table names with curly brackets. That way table prefix (if any) will be added automatically. It's better to use that way all the time.

This is how your query should look like:

`SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'page' ORDER BY created DESC`.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution:

```
SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = 'page' ORDER BY created DESC
```